# Simple Browser/Website web app mobile app/shortcut

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, web

I have a website/web app which I want to make available on mobile devices.

The website is responsive and can be used inthe mobile browser, but I want to make it available on google play / app store. My question is: how could I create a simple app that is actually a browser, which would run natively on the phone but load my web page in full screen?

Any simple solutions or frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are different approaches to solve your questions I am trying to give you some rough idea with following two approaches.

Easy and simple one

1) Use web views and call home page url that's all.

For better performance.

2) Create a REST apis with only required data for your mobile app . And then use either web view or create your own views and show it to user . In this case if you create your native view then app will perform faster but development will take time.